# How to pull an image column from the database and display on POWERBI dashboard?

Tags: database, image, powerbi

Currently we have a database column that is of type IMAGE.  We need the ability to query this table and display the image on a POWERBI dashboard.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

On the Data tab from left ribbon, choose the image url column.

In the Header ribbon in the Modelling -> Properties section -> Select "Data Category" - > "Image URL" (second from the bottom)

[image]

Comment: Image `URL` and a data `IMAGE` column are not the same; one is a URL, one is the image itself.